# How to read xml content with different roots with golang encoding/xml

Tags: xml, go

My current task at hand is to read different xml payloads coming into the system with golang. The xml payloads might have different root tag names. A different root tag name means the xml has a completely different meaning.
I've been playing around with encoding/xml for quite some time now, but I've found no way to read those xml payloads with one Unmarshal call without manipulating it before or without doing a pre-parsing in order to extract the root name.

This is a simplified example of the task at hand, reading 2 xmls separately:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Boxes struct {
    Length []float64
}

type Bottles struct {
    Diameter []float64
}   

var Box_xml = []byte("<Boxes><Length>45</Length><Length>41</Length></Boxes>")
var Bottle_xml = []byte("<Bottles><Diameter>23</Diameter><Diameter>25</Diameter></Bottles>")

func main() {
    box := Boxes{}
    xml.Unmarshal(Box_xml, &box)
    bottle := Bottles{}
    xml.Unmarshal(Bottle_xml, &bottle)
    fmt.Println(box, bottle)
}
```

This code prints

```
{[45 41]} {[23 25]}
```

My current "best" solution for processing an arbitrary incoming message in a single call would be to add a root tag to those xmls and read them in a central struct - like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Boxes struct {
    Length []float64
}

type Bottles struct {
    Diameter []float64
}

type Delivery struct {
    Boxes Boxes
    Bottles Bottles
}   

var Box_xml = []byte("<Delivery><Boxes><Length>45</Length><Length>41</Length></Boxes></Delivery>")
var Bottle_xml = []byte("<Delivery><Bottles><Diameter>23</Diameter><Diameter>25</Diameter></Bottles></Delivery>")

func main() {
    delivery := Delivery{}
    xml.Unmarshal(Box_xml, &delivery)
    fmt.Println(delivery )
    delivery = Delivery{}
    xml.Unmarshal(Bottle_xml, &delivery)
    fmt.Println(delivery)
}
```

This code prints

```
{{[45 41]} {[]}}
{{[]} {[23 25]}}
```

and that would be a good way of structuring the result for later processing.

How can I do it without having to add an artificial root tag to the payload?

Comment: Use [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) like so https://play.golang.com/p/XO8GIjEWsPA.

Comment: ... if you don't want to use embedding, doing what you're doing right now is perfectly reasonable, at least in my opinion. Another option would be to implement the xml.Unmarshaler interface.

Comment: Embedding also came to my mind, but it would pose problems with similarly named tags in different xmls (that I could overcome by naming them differently and adding the xml:field tags to the structs). It's probably also less hassle than implementing the interface.

Comment: You can use all features available inside `encoding/xml` package and start processing xml input token by token (node by node). Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can create xml decoder and use `Token` method for parsing xml input node by node. It will not parse all document. Check out more [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Token).

> Token returns the next XML token in the input stream. At the end of the input stream, Token returns nil, io.EOF.
>
> Slices of bytes in the returned token data refer to the parser's internal buffer and remain valid only until the next call to Token. To acquire a copy of the bytes, call CopyToken or the token's Copy method.
>
> Token expands self-closing elements such as 
>  into separate start and end elements returned by successive calls.
>
> Token guarantees that the StartElement and EndElement tokens it returns are properly nested and matched: if Token encounters an unexpected end element or EOF before all expected end elements, it will return an error.

It is just an example how can you determine what type of xml do you have and what struct you need to parse into:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type Boxes struct {
    Length []float64
}

type Bottles struct {
    Diameter []float64
}

type DeliveryBoxes struct {
    Boxes   Boxes
}

type DeliveryBottles struct {
    Bottles Bottles
}

const (
    BoxXML    = "<Delivery><Boxes><Length>45</Length><Length>41</Length></Boxes></Delivery>"
    BottleXML = "<Delivery><Bottles><Diameter>23</Diameter><Diameter>25</Diameter></Bottles></Delivery>"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    var xmlReader = strings.NewReader(BoxXML)
    var decoder = xml.NewDecoder(xmlReader)

    // start with a first token 'Delivery'
    t, err := decoder.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // next token is a next node: 'Boxes' or 'Bottles'
    t, err = decoder.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    startElement := t.(xml.StartElement)

    // create new reader to start from the beginning
    xmlReader = strings.NewReader(BoxXML)

    switch startElement.Name.Local {
    case "Boxes":
        var delivery DeliveryBoxes
        if err := xml.NewDecoder(xmlReader).Decode(&delivery); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        log.Println(delivery)
    case "Bottles":
        var delivery DeliveryBottles
        if err := xml.NewDecoder(xmlReader).Decode(&delivery); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        log.Println(delivery)
    }
}
```

In general, we parse first two nodes to check struct type and then parse full xml input using defined struct. You can move switch statement to a single function and use `interface{}` type for `delivery` variable. Anyway, it is an example to show you that you can determine the data format of your xml input without parsing the whole input.